# Why does this program output “11” in a loop when use var and with let if works?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, let

Why output is 10  when use var and with let it works the loop.
Edit the output is 11 but why let and var are different

```js
var funcions = [];

for (var x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
  funcions.push(function() {
    console.log(x);
  });
}

funcions.forEach(
  function(func) {
    func();
  }
);
```

I know that `let`, is a signal that the variable may be reassigned, such as a counter in a loop, or a value swap in an algorithm. It also signals that the variable will be used only in the block it’s defined in, which is not always the entire containing function.

Comment: Note: you actually get `11` since you are using `x <= 10` instead of `x < 10`.

Comment: By the time you execute each of the functions, x is 11.

Comment: When using `var x`, `x` is not scoped to each iteration of the loop.

Comment: yes 11 sorry mm thank you

Comment: but I want why let vs var sorry I have a bad english